# Addition of complex 3D arrays in pyopencl

Tags: python, complex-numbers, pyopencl

I'm trying to add 2 three dimensional complex arrays with help of python library pyopencl. The result achieved on gpu differs from the reference result achieved with use of cpu. Why does GPU code do not provide correct addition of complex numbers? I expect corresponding variables res and ref to be equal to each other. The code I use:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fftn, ifftn
from numpy.random import random, normal
import os


os.environ['PYOPENCL_COMPILER_OUTPUT'] = '1'

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

Lx = 100
Ly = 100
Lz = 1
L = Lx * Ly * Lz


const = np.zeros(4).astype(np.float32)
const[0] = Lx
const[1] = Ly
const[2] = Lz
const[3] = L

const_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR,    hostbuf=const)


arr1 = np.random.rand(Lz, Ly, Lx).astype(np.float32)
arr2 = np.random.rand(Lz, Ly, Lx).astype(np.float32)

F1 = fftn(arr1)
F2 = fftn(arr2)

out = np.zeros((Lz,Ly,Lx)).astype(np.complex64)
out_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY, out.nbytes)

do_it_code = """
#include <pyopencl-complex.h>
__kernel void doit(__global const float *constants,
__global const cfloat_t *IN1,__global const cfloat_t *IN2,
__global cfloat_t *out)

{   int z = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);
    int x = get_global_id(2);
    const int len = constants[3];
  const int lx = constants[0];
const int ly = constants[1];
const int lz = constants[2];
const int pl = lx * ly;
int i = x + y * lx + z * pl;

if (x <= lx-1 && y <= ly-1 && z <= lz-1) {
out[i] = cfloat_add(IN1[i],IN2[i]);

};
};
"""
bld_do_it = cl.Program(ctx, do_it_code).build()

def do_it(a,b):
    a_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR,     hostbuf=a.astype(np.complex64))
    b_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=b.astype(np.complex64))
    launch = bld_do_it.doit(queue, a.shape, None, const_buf, a_buf, b_buf, out_buf)
    launch.wait()
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, out, out_buf)

    return out

ref=F1+F2
print(ref)
print("_________")
res=do_it(F1,F2)
print(res)
```

Comment: The difference in results seems to be few digits after comma so that suggests it might be due to different FPU units that are on CPU and accelerator. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11209209/4899330)

Comment: no, the difference is way more than a few few digits after comma.

Comment: Yep, you are right, there is more than this - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To figure out what's wrong usually is good to work on much smaller data set. Let's set `Lx=Ly=2` and check what we get:

```
[[[ 3.40425836+0.j -2.09837677+0.j]
  [-0.27708016+0.j  0.60454108+0.j]]]
_________
[[[ 3.4042583 +0.j -0.27708015+0.j]
  [-2.0983768 +0.j  0.60454106+0.j]]]
```

The numbers are almost identical, just not all in the places they were expected to be. Simple transpose can fix this:

`res=np.transpose(res, (0,2,1))`

and then result matches the reference result:

```
[[[ 3.4042583 +0.j -2.0983768 +0.j]
  [-0.27708015+0.j  0.60454106+0.j]]]
```

There is still little discrepancy between results - after few digits after comma - but that can be explained by different FPU units being used between CPU and GPU (in my case). More on this can be read for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11209209/4899330).

This should not need a transpose - Lx,Ly,Lz placing must be wrong somewhere - I will let OP to figure out this.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sence!

Answer (score 0):

I found this update to the OP's GPU code solved the transposition error noted in the discussion thread - and left as an 'exercise for the student' in one response.  It turned out, for me at least, to be non-trivial to figure out so I thought this might be helpful to share:

```
do_it_code = """
#include <pyopencl-complex.h>
__kernel void doit(__global const float *constants,
__global const cfloat_t *IN1,__global const cfloat_t *IN2,
__global cfloat_t *out)

{   int z = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);
    int x = get_global_id(2);
    const int len = constants[3];
  const int lx = constants[0];
const int ly = constants[1];
const int lz = constants[2];
const int pl = lx * ly;
const int pl2 = lz * ly;
int i = x + y * lx + z * pl;
int i2 = x*pl2 + y*lz  + z;

if (x <= lx-1 && y <= ly-1 && z <= lz-1) {
out[i] = cfloat_add(IN1[i2],IN2[i2]);

};
};
"""
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).